# Command line to run a program with both xlwt and abaqusConstants modules

Tags: xlrd, xlwt

Windows Machine, Python 2.4.
I have a program that imports both xlwt/xlrd and abaqusConstants module.

When I run my program with the command line: abaqus python abc.py, I get "ImportError: No module named xlwt/xlrd"

When I run my program with the command line: c:\python24\python.exe abc.py, I get "ImportError: No module named abaqusConstants".

The program ran perfectly when I ran it on my system where xlrd/xlwt was present in c:\python24\lib and Abaqus was installed in C-drive. When I tried to access xlrd/xlwt from my organisation's common share, the above problem appeared.

Is it because Abaqus is not present in the common share? How do I rectify this issue? Please tell me what command line to use.

Answer (score 0):

the module abaqusConstants is only available in abaqus kernel executions of python so you need to be running it with abaqus python. Make sure that your PYTHONPATH variable is set properly to include the directory where xlwt/xlrd exists. see [Using matplotlib (for python 2.6) with Abaqus 6.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382382/using-matplotlib-for-python-2-6-with-abaqus-6-12) for a similar issue.