# Using matplotlib (for python 2.6) with Abaqus 6.12

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-2.6, finite-element-analysis

I'm wondering if any of you use matplotlib for your python codes that are coupled with ABAQUS. I really want to load matplotlib onto the abaqus-python interface. I'm using ABAQUS 6.12, which has python 2.6. Also, I'm using Windows 64 bit.

However, when I download the matplotlib for python 2.6, it fails to install and says that

> > "Python 2.6 required, which is not found in the Registry."

Could anyone help me out? Does anyone know of a step-by-step way to install matplotlib such that it works for Abaqus 6.12?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Note:  For those unfamiliar with FEA Software, the Abaqus Scripting Interface is an extension of the Python object-oriented programming language, and comes with ABAQUS/CAE.

Comment: did you install python with administrative rights? Can you execute Python code on your machine? Maybe download python-xy, where everything you need is included already? http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/

Comment: @Jared don't forget you can accept the answer (and upvote it) if you want...

Answer (score 1):

I use `Matplotlib 1.3.0` with Abaqus 6.11. Everything 64 bit. I believe with Abaqus 6.12 will work as well. The procedure is (using the same configuration as mine, but I believe newer versions of NumPy and Matplotlib will work as well):

- [install Python 2.7 64 bit](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/python-2.7.5.amd64.msi)
- [install NumPy 1.7.1 64 bit](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
- [install Matplotlib 1.3.0 64 bit](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html)

Configure your environment variable `PYTHONPATH` pointing to were `matplotlib` is installed before importing it from Abaqus.

You may get a RuntimeWarning like:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:71:
RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Python; most PIL functions will be disabled
```

But you can use most of `matplotlib`'s features from Abaqus.