# Trying to use matplotlib with ABAQUS. Getting error involving dateutil

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-dateutil, finite-element-analysis

I am wondering if any of you use matplotlib for your python codes that are coupled with ABAQUS. I'm using ABAQUS 6.12, which has python 2.6.  Also, I'm using Windows 64 bit.

I have downloaded matplotlib, but when I import matplotlib onto the ABAQUS-Python scripting interface, I get the following error:

> ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil

Could anyone help me out?  How do I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Note: For those unfamiliar with FEA Software, the Abaqus Scripting Interface is an extension of the Python object-oriented programming language, and comes with ABAQUS/CAE.

Comment: have you tried installing dateutil: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil

Answer (score 1):

I got matplotlib working in Abaqus Python. I am also  using Abaqus 6.12 in Windows 7 x64.

Here are the steps I took:

1) Get matplotlib 1.0.1, which works with Python 2.6.2, at

http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/

For Windows x64 you need 'matplotlib-1.0.1.win-amd64-py2.6.exe'

2) Extract folders and files from the archive (exe file) into '\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.12-x\tools\SMApy\Lib\site-packages'

You can create your own folder (e.g 'custom') in 'site-packages' to prevent messing up with Abaqus files and folders. In this case, just add a file custom.pth file that contains a line "custom" (see simulia.pth for an example) or append the path to custom folder in your script.

3) With this done, I get an error "No module named Tkinter". So I also append the path to Tkinter.py by adding a line

"path.append('\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.12-x\tools\SMApy\Lib\lib-tk')" in my script.

I tested only some basic stuff in matplotlib so I am not sure if everything will work.

The way suggested at [Using matplotlib (for python 2.6) with Abaqus 6.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382382/using-matplotlib-for-python-2-6-with-abaqus-6-12) looks better but I personally couldn't force Abaqus Python to use "my" Numpy 1.7 instead of Numpy 1.4 embedded in Abaqus Python.

First two steps are taken from `http://62.213.117.104/blog2/serendipity/index.php?/archives/28-Python_i_Abaqus._Ispolzovanie_bibliotek_numpy_i_matplotlib.html`